# Mass enable entries

Tags: entries, query, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set statuses to enabled in mysql. Around 150k entries.

The tables are `elements` and `elements_sites`. Set status to `1`.

The query runs OK. In the cp is also everything fine but entries don't show up on the site itself.

By manually entering one random entry disabling and enabling it again it works as expected.

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

The `resave` CLI command has helped ([`./craft resave/entries`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#resave-entries)).